# CentOS 6.5 nmblookup not found

Tags: centos, samba

After installing Samba (yum install samba) on a fresh CentOS 6.5 install, I cannot run nmblookup ("command not found"). I also tried searching the file system and could not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search use the command:

```
yum provides '*bin/nmblookup'
```

The package name is `samba-client`.